# Laravel angular js get Login Customer name

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I am using Laravel and angular js

I follwed this [Link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) tutorial everthing is working fine but my problem is i don't know how to display Login customer name and mail id

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('authApp')
        .controller('UserController', UserController);  

    function UserController($http) {

        var vm = this;

        vm.users;
        vm.error;

        vm.getUsers = function() {

            // This request will hit the index method in the AuthenticateController
            // on the Laravel side and will return the list of users
            $http.get('api/authenticate').success(function(users) {
                vm.users = users;
            }).error(function(error) {
                vm.error = error;
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access to `vm.users` object.

First, you have to alias your controller in your view.

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as user">
```

Your controller (this) becomes accessible with `user`.

Then you have to iterate your `users` object with `ngRepeat` directive.

```
<span ng-repeat="iteratedUser in user.users">
```

Full view code:

```
<div ng-controller="UserController as user">
    <span ng-repeat="iteratedUser in user.users">
        Name: {{iteratedUser.name}}
    </span>
</div>
```

If you need more explanations, tell me in comments :)

**Edit**: Don't forget to call your `getUsers` function! Else, data won't be fetched.

Comment: Sorry i need current Login customer name only

Comment: Then just display customer name :) I'm editing answer

Comment: No not display anything

Comment: Please you need to show more code, possible errors in console etc.

Comment: No error my full code here https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: This is not your code, this is a tutorial I'm not going to reproduce for helping you.

Comment: Actually in this tutorial aslo they didn't mention how to fetch customer name

Comment: This is explained here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps#toc-setting-up-the-users-state ....

Comment: Where in screen shot it will show but there is no code

Comment: https://github.com/scotch-io/laravel-angular-token-authentication/blob/scotch/public/views/userView.html

Comment: <h3>Users</h3> this much only there where is curret user name

Comment: I don't understand what you want, sorry.Let's continue in chat if you really want to explain me something about your problem, but StackOverflow community is not a tutorial assistance.

Comment: I just want to login customer name that;s it